# How to run curl in Linux terminal using java

Tags: java

Tried with following:

`ProcessBuilder`
`Runtime.exec()`

but not able to execute?

My curl request

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder( "curl",
    "-H Content-type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8",
    "-d @acd.xml" , 
    "-k "
    ,"\"https://127.0.0.1:4443/s1/ssdces/dfing/v2\"", 
    "--tlsdv1");
```

I got an error

`curl: (1) Protocol  "https not supported or disabled in libcurl`

but I have already specified -k for insecure connection

`curl --version
curl 7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.21 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
Protocols: tftp ftp telnet dict ldap ldaps http file https ftps scp sftp 
Features: GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz`

Terminal is working fine but when try to use using java it gives above error

Comment: Please post all the necessary code to reproduce the issue and post the exact error you get, along with the stacktrace.

Comment: There are *zero* details in this question.

Comment: but I am not getting any error..

Comment: Have you read/captured `ErrorStream`?

Comment: ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(
      "curl"
      ,"-H Content-type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8"
      ,"-d @acd.xml"
      , "-k \"https://127.0.0.1:4443/s1/ssdces/dfing/v2/\""
      , "--tlsdv1");

Comment: Please [edit] the question to add any further details. The comment section is not suitable for code. Also: why do you want to run a command-line curl instead of using the appropriate Java classes to access the web site?

Comment: Try to remove the space in the `"k "` argument, this is just a weird hunch.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that will work?

```
 Process p = new ProcessBuilder("myCommand", "myArg").start();
```